# How do I prevent getting an Out of Memory error?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Often, when I join a game, I'm able to play for approximately 15 minutes before the game straight up crashes on me, telling me that there was an Out of Memory error. How do I fix this? I am on PC, not Mac.

Comment: Well, for starters, how much RAM do you have?

Comment: Adding to @Timmy_Jim 's comment, how often do these crashes occur. And when did they start? Any installed programs and or viruses that you're unaware of?

Comment: I use a lap top, and currently not at home. I use Avast and run virus checks quite frequently. I have no clue when they started.

Comment: @PacmanLP - Turn off your Antivirus when playing TF2. AV programs have a habit of going nuts every time a program writes/deletes a lot of files (such as temp files created by games).

Answer (score 2):

## Solution 1

I've been searching around and found the answer on the Steam Forum.
Here is a slight paraphrase / quotation of the answer-er (credits at the end).

> To start troubleshooting, we need to make sure your *game installation is unmodified*.
> First, you should delete your `tf` folder located in either, `"C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\[your steam username]\team fortress 2"` **or** `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\[your steam username]\team fortress 2"`.
> If you have scripts, maps, etc that you would like to keep, you can **copy** those out to a **safe place** before you delete them.
> Next, you'll want to reset all your configuration settings. Deleting the `tf` folder should do this, but just to be safe, set the `-autoconfig` flag for Team Fortress 2.
> To do this, open your Steam library, right-click TF2, click Properties, and in the General tab, click Set Launch Options. Erase everything that is in there (if there is anything) and type in
>
> > -autoconfig
>
> Close these windows, then start up TF2. Don't change any settings, and see if it still crashes.

Thanks to `scy1192` from Steam for this paraphrased answer.

## Solution 2

Another solution mentioned, was to change your Video Settings: ideally disabling the Multi-Core Rendering settings. To achieve this, navigate to the Option 's 'Advanced' tab - you should find `Multi-Core Rendering` somewhere among the several other settings, *do not mess with them* - when you find it, disable it.

When you join a TF2-Match, you will probably notice a significant FPS-Drop depending on whether your computer relies on or semi-relies on Multiple CPU Cores.

This is a side-effect at most, it may affect game-play performance, but it is sure to stop any 'random crashes'.

## Solution 3

This ties directly back to Solution 1, in that you need to 'clean up' your files in the `tf` folder (save the important or essentials to a safe-zone, then delete the contents of the `tf` folder). If you haven't skimmed over it yet, go back to it! The reason why this is classed as another solution, is that many, many, many people have been referencing this exact process... (should I have given credit?)

Anyway, to **Solution 4** (I feel inclined to link it to Solution 3, as 3 is just a referral-call) !
My solution revolves around changing your video settings to the absolute lowest and shutting down any of the computer's background processes. If this doesn't work, all I can say is RIP.

Anyway, I hope that this helps and gets you back to your game. Good luck.